# Invalid argument hGetContents in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm trying to sort a list of ints and print them out, but am receiving this exception:

```
Exception: <stdin>: hGetContents: invalid argument (Bad file descriptor)
```

The program:

```
import Data.List

main :: IO ()
main = do
    interact maxTri
    putStrLn ""

readInt :: String -> Int
readInt = read

maxTri :: String -> String
maxTri = show .
    sort .
    map readInt .
    words
```

Comment: How are you compiling/running this program? (Are you running this in ghci?)

Comment: Yes ghci. I use :load *path*.hs then run using :main

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`interact` (semi-)closes the input stream. This does not play well if you are in ghci, which expects to continue using the input stream.

Compile and run your program with

```
ghc path.hs
path
```

and this problem should not appear.

Comment: With `ghc`, it doesn't produce any output for me. If I pass `interact id` instead then it works. Compiler: 7.8.4

Comment: My understanding was that you shouldn't do *anything* with a semi-closed handle. As in, once you call a function that semi-closes the handle, you can't do any normal handle things with that handle anymore.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Are you able to get any output for this ? I'm confused that this works perfectly fine with `interact id`.

Comment: @Sibi It produces the expected output for me. If I enter `2\n1\n3\n\EOT` I get back `[1,2,3]\n\EOT`.

Comment: @Sibi (Perhaps you are not closing your input -- on Linux-alikes, this can be done with Ctrl-D.)

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks, that makes it work. Interestingly for `interact id`, it seems I don't need to use `Ctrl + D`.

Comment: @Sibi Sorting requires traversing the entire input, of course. Can't hope to know what the smallest number is until you've at least seen them all.